# How to set constraints in android studio

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I've searched online and I saw that in Android Studio is possible to set the Constraint Layout with the blue prints, but I can't find them. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

1.Ensure you have the **Android Studio 2.2 Preview** & latest **Android Support Repository (version 32 or higher)**:

```
Click Tools > Android > SDK Manager.

Click the SDK Tools tab.

Select Android Support Repository, then click OK.
```

[image: Support Repo]

2.You have to add following in your compile dependency in `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
```

then you also have to update your gradle plugin also (Main Project's **`build.gradle`**)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2'
```

Or you can use the latest:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
```

3.In the toolbar or sync notification, click Sync Project with Gradle Files.

4.To add a new constraint layout to your project:
Right-click on your module's layout directory, then click New > XML > Layout XML.
Enter a name for the layout and enter **`android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`** for the Root Tag.

**OR**

To convert an existing layout to a constraint layout:

```
Open your existing layout in Android Studio 
and select the Design tab at the bottom of the editor window.
In the Component Tree window, 
right-click the layout and click Convert <layout> 
to ConstraintLayout.
```

Source

[Constraint Layout](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-editor)

Comment: I did it, and now? Where can I find the blue prints?

Comment: You have to replace your Root layout with **`android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`** and then refresh layout

Comment: I've added that line in the build.gradle (module: app) file, but when I click "sync" it gives me an error: "failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint ecc"

Comment: And when I create a new xml file and add that root, it gives me this error: "rendering problems, the following classes could not be found: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"

Comment: you have to update your gradle plugin as well This should work: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2'

Or you can use the latest: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'

Comment: So i have to add: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
in the build.gradle (module: app) file under "dependencies"?

Comment: Well actually I'm still trying to solve the problem. Another user said that I have to have the 2.2 version of android studio

Comment: Actually its true..docs says that it requires Android Studio 2.2 Preview version

Comment: You need 2.2 beta 1, and use: compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha6' (many improvements from alpha 2)

Comment: this moved all my widgets to 0,0  :(

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to first create a `Relative Layout` properly and then convert it to `Constraint Layout`.

**To convert an existing layout to a constraint layout:**

> Open your existing layout in Android Studio and select the Design tab
>   at the bottom of the editor window.
>
> In the Component Tree window, right-click the layout and click
>   Convert  to ConstraintLayout.

Comment: When I right-click on the layout there is no "Convert to ConstraintLayout"

Comment: are you using Android Studio 2.1 or later?

Comment: it requires Android Studio 2.2 as described in the link http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-editor

Comment: But when I click "check for updates" it says there's nothing

Comment: i update settings instead of stable channel look for beta channel updates

Comment: So I don't understand. How can I upgrade to 2.2?

Comment: now next time when you will check for update it will show you updates available

Comment: follow this link http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview2available